# Rotten Rain drain grate

Tags: drainage

The steel grate on my garden rain drain is rotten. Can I just replace the grate or do I have to replace the channel as well. The grates and channels seem to be complete when bought. I would prefer to just replace the grates. I think the channel is concrete.
[image]

Comment: Where is your photo of drain and channel?  Please resend.  Did you purchase this thing? I for one have never heard of this, where is it that you live? If you did purchase this you should ask the vendor if you can get replacement parts. Otherwise, take some measurements, pictures, go to a steel worker and they can make you a new grate fairly inexpensively.

Comment: Photo would be useful, but are you talking about an ACO type rain drain? Where there's a grid on top and a channel (these days, plastic) beneath?

Comment: Steel does not rust quickly. Have you picked up the grate and cleaned it off?

Comment: Yes an ACO type rain drain,is it possible to just buy the grates as the concrete channel does not need replacing

Answer (score 5):

First, let me say I'm mystified as to why your question has been migrated to Home Improvement - your question is about a Landscaping product, so posting it on SE Garden and Landscaping was exactly the right thing to do. Unfortunately, it had been moved by the time I logged back on late tonight, so too late for me to give a no vote.

ACO themselves do supply replacement grids, as they're called, rather than grates (well, in the UK) but they need to know the size and whether your grid was an ACO in the first place. If not, they may not be prepared to supply, or may not have a product of the right size and shape. It may be that the drain and grid itself are no longer of a size that is produced, regardless of who the original supplier was - if you can establish which company made your grids (isn't that a name I can see embossed on one side of the grid?), then that's who to contact to see if replacements are available.